# setuptools incorporating dependency into own package

Tags: python, setuptools

I have two setuptools packages (managed via `setup.py` which imports and calls `setuptools.setup()`). Both share the same base namespace packages: `foo.bar.util` and `foo.bar.service`. The second depends on the first, and is listed in `install_requires`. The package is organized with all `MANIFEST.in` items under `src/`, which just grafts `src/`, and then recursively excludes `*.pyc` and `__pycache__/**`. `namespace_packages` is set as `['foo', 'foo.bar']` for both packages.

It works as expected. I can build a sdist, push it up to a private PyPI, `pip install` from that, etc. However, when the second package requires the first, and I run any `python setup.py` command (`test`, `develop`, `install`, etc.), it totally bombs.

Weirdly enough, when I fire up the CPython interpreter after `develop` fails, the first package is there. However, any packages that the first package depends on (like `more-itertools`), causes attempts to load those packages to error. Somehow, the code is being incorporated, but the dependencies are not.

Finally, if I turn on `DISTUTILS_DEBUG=1` and `SETUPTOOLS_DEBUG=1`, I see the fetch from the private PyPI. I see the attempt to package the `bdist_egg`. Here's where it's weird: right after the `bdist_egg` output line, there's no more mention of this package?

I've been wracking my brain and searching constantly. Has anyone run into anything like this?

EDIT:

So, I packaged my stuff under `src/` as outlined here:
http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/.

Looking at the `python setup.py develop` `DISTUTILS_DEBUG=1` output, I see that the `graft src` directive in `MANIFEST.in` is including `src/<required code>`, `src/<this egg-info>`, and `src/<required egg-info>`. Huh. Weird. And then it grabs everything again as `src/src/`! What's going on?

EDIT:

OK, this is me trying to be too clever for the Python ecosystem. I created an egg template for my company. One of our objectives is to have a template that's *refreshable*. `setup.py` falls into that - if we want to inject custom targets, we can run a **Template Updater** Bash script and it will clone all of our GitHub repos, make the modifications, and optionally commit and push them up. This includes Tox and Travis.

So what I did was import a `setup_cfg.py` from `setup.py`. The former has the package name and version and is ignored by the Updater. The second is boilerplate.

The issue is that on `python setup.py <develop|install>`, all `setup_cfg.py` ended up in the same spot (I assume). And so the act of installing the dependent package actually installed the package-in-question. When it came time to install the package-in-question, it got skipped.

Flipping this backwards, where we have a `setup_template.py` that's the boilerplate, and `setup.py` not actually having the `setuptools` code, but only the project name and version, works perfectly!

It's unfortunate that Python doesn't have env-internal package version management or cleanliness. :(.

Now, the only issue I'm still facing is this doesn't work with Tox for some reason. I suspect some weirdness with namespace packages. I'm going to go look at how Zope does testing, because I know they use namespace packages.